# Python change NaN value with df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi everyone I've an excel sheet that i read with pandas.
This is the output :

```
                              vlan  ajout
0  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    NaN
1                         Vlan TAM    NaN
2                          Vlam EM    NaN
3  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    NaN
```

I'd like to change `NaN` values to "vlan 10" when in the column "vlan" find the word `"Controleur"`. The futur output i like to have is :

```
                              vlan  ajout
0  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    vlan 10
1                         Vlan TAM    
2                          Vlam EM    
3  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    vlan 10
```

At the moment i tried many and many possibilites and i have this code that is the closer to the reality that i can find :

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'.\test.xlsx')
df['ajout'] = df['ajout'].fillna(0)
df.loc[df['vlan'] == "Controleur", df['ajout']] = 'vlan 10'
print(df)
```

Sadly it doesn't work and the output is really bad

```
                              vlan  ajout  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
0  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1                         Vlan TAM    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2                          Vlam EM    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  Vlan Controleur Wifi\nVlan bleu    0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I don't know why so many columns are added and why my `'ajout'` column stay fixed to 0

If someone has an idea or a lead, i'll take it

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find `Controleur` in Series value

```py
df.loc[df['vlan'].str.contains("Controleur"), 'ajout'] = 'vlan 10'
```

You can also try `df.mask` and `np.where`

```py
df['ajout'] = df['ajout'].mask(df['vlan'].str.contains("Controleur"), 'vlan 10')

# or

df['ajout'] = np.where(df['vlan'].str.contains("Controleur"), 'vlan 10', df['ajout'])
```

Comment: So many time I lost on this haha
Thanks a lot, I accept your answer

Comment: All of yours answers are working, i'll check the differences between them.
But is there a better solution or a "cleanest" solution among these 3 ?

Comment: @Luc_08 For the cleanest, I may choose the `loc` because it doesn't repeat `df['vlan']` like the other two.